# Otimizar método Java utilizando o conceito de Escopos

Tags: java, android, desempenho, otimização, escopo-de-variáveis

Bem a algum tempo atrás, quando tive algumas aulas de [J2ME para Mobile](https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/faq/whatis_j2me.xml) (praticamente falecido ✞), onde fui apresentado a um conceito de escopo até então desconhecido por mim, que seria esse:

```
{
    // cria um novo escopo
}
```

Onde em qualquer lugar de um método é possível forçar novos escopos. Pesquisando encontrei algumas fontes e referências que podem ser o artigo [Thinking in Java](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ304_006.htm) no site Linuxtopia e [esta outra questão do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17647194/2766598).

Então buscando otimizar alguns recursos em meus aplicativos Android, pensei em refatorar meus códigos para tirar proveito dessa forma de gerenciamento de recursos, só que não tenho conhecimento se isso realmente pode fazer alguma diferença.

Então apresento o seguinte exemplo, para contextualizar minha dúvida:

**Exemplo:**

Suponhamos que eu tenha uma `class` grande que aloque muitos recursos ao ser inicializada:

```java
public class ClasseGrande{

    // ...

    public void alocaMuitosRecursos(){
        // Aqui inicia varios atributos da ClasseGrande()
        // ...
    }

    public String obtemResultado(){
        return "Resultado da classe grande";
    }    
}
```

E as 3 seguintes abordagens de utilização:

Abordagem 1 (A minha atual):

```
// tudo no mesmo scope
public void testScopeMethod1(){
    ClasseGrande classeGrande = new ClasseGrande();
    classeGrande.alocaMuitosRecursos();

    // ... usar a classe grande

    String resultado = classeGrande.obtemResultado();

    // agora não se utiliza mais a classe grande só se manipula seu resultado

    // faz vários processos com o atributo resultado

    // ...

    // termina método, e só aqui todos os recursos são liberados para GC. Certo?
}
```

Abordagem 2 (utilizando métodos para dividir escopos):

```
// utiliza método para trocar de scope
public void testScopeMethod2(){
    String resultado = processaClasseGrande();

    // faz vários processos com o atributo resultado

    // ...

    // termina método, e libera os recursos do método testScopeMethod2
}

private String processaClasseGrande(){
    ClasseGrande classeGrande = new ClasseGrande();
    classeGrande.alocaMuitosRecursos();

    // ... usar a classe grande

    return classeGrande.obtemResultado();

    // aqui a classe grande já é liberada, pois finalizou-se seu escopo de método. Certo?
}
```

Abordagem 3 (utilizando sub escopos dentro do próprio método, logo após utilizar o recurso):

```
// com sub scope no método
public void testScopeMethod3(){
    String resultado;
    {
        ClasseGrande classeGrande = new ClasseGrande();
        classeGrande.alocaMuitosRecursos();

        // ... usar a classe grande

        resultado = classeGrande.obtemResultado();
        // aqui a classe grande já é liberada, pois finalizou-se seu escopo. Certo?
    }

    // agora não se utiliza mais a classe grande só se manipula seu resultado

    // faz vários processos com o atributo resultado

    // ...

    // termina método, e libera os recursos do método testScopeMethod, mas a classe grande já foi libera logo após ser utilizada. Certo?
}
```

**Perguntas:**

- Isso faz realmente diferença de performance? Por que?
- Se faz diferença, as abordagens 2 e 3 apresentam diferenças de
  performance? Onde e por que?
- Se isso faz algum sentido, seria uma boa prática ter isso em mente
  para projetos robustos, principalmente pensando em dispositivos
  moveis?

Comment: Fernando, você poderia verificar isso no **Memory Monitor** do Android Studio, junto com uma chamada ao Garbage Collector, mas se talvez o processamento feito até a perda da referência (no caso 1) for pequeno, não haverá diferença na mudança de escopo. Você também pode atribuir `null` à referência, para tentar liberar logo o objeto grande (chamando o GC depois).

Comment: @Wakim, você diz fazer chamadas explicitas ao Garbage Collector (`System.gc()`)? Pois essa minha duvida seria não somente para métodos robustos, mas sim para sempre tentar ir por esse caminho, tentando minimizar os recursos a cada parte da aplicação, buscando assim um resultado mais eficiente e otimizado, e a ideia de escopo me parece uma forma mais limpa e legível de fazer isso, comparado a setar `null` e chamar explicitamente o GC. Mas não descarto a possibilidade se for para obter melhor otimização de recursos, pois hoje estou enfrentando graves problemas de `OutOfMemory` em meu aplicativo.

Comment: @Wakim, e a respeito de sua dica de utilizar o Memory Monitor do Android Studio, vou tentar criar um caso de testes aqui e ver os resultados. Obrigado pela dica. =D

Comment: Sim, seria a chamada ao `System.gc`, mas ele não garante que irá rodar na hora, ele escalona uma execução. `OutOfMemory` pode ser sinal de **MemoryLeaks**, recentemente a *Square* liberou uma ferramenta que ajuda a analisar a existencia deles, chamada [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), talvez valha a pena analizar se não está havendo esse tipo de problema no seu app. Outra coisa poderia ser o uso de `Object Pools`, para reduzir a quantidade de objetos criados, dê uma olhada nesse vídeo do [Colt McAnlis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McAvq5SkeTk) para entender.

Comment: Realmente usar escopos é mais "bonito" do que setar null e chamar o GC, mas serviria para casos em que você aloca grandes quantidades, e em pontos específicos, não pelo código inteiro. Talvez seja o caso de usar a configuração de `largeHeap` no seu `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: @Wakim, vou analisar suas dicas principalmente a respeito do **LeakCanary**, que pelo que vi pode ajudar a identificar o que está causando a **MemoryLeak** no aplicativo. E o `largeHeap` já estou utilizando, meus problemas são pontuais em alguns dispositivos de baixo padrão, como alguns aparelhos da Genesis, por exemplo. Mas quero pelo menos minimizar esses problemas nesses dispositivos, o que já me garantiria uma maior confiabilidade em aparelhos superior.

Comment: Fernando, se ainda não conseguiu resolver o problema, posso dar mais uma sugestão. O [**Fresco**](http://frescolib.org/), biblioteca do facebook, consegue fazer alocação de memória em área especial do Android, onde possui menos restrição de tamanho... Será que não vale a pena uma tentativa de fazer a alocação desse objeto grande lá, manipular e depois desalocar? Nunca usei essa área, mas pelo que eu ouvi falar, você é quem gerencia a alocação e desalocação, então precisa tomar cuidado para não esquecer nada lá...

Comment: @Wakim, resolver não resolvi, mas já melhorei algumas situações, as telas que causam problemas de **OutOfMemory** nos dispositivos citados, são as telas de Catalogo, onde são telas com grids de imagens, já estou redimensionando as imagens para o tamanho adequado ao carrega-la para a memória, e já estou carregando por demanda e desalocando por demanda, conforme o usuário desce e sobe no _scroll_ da pagina, mas esporadicamente, não é sempre, **OutOfMemory** acontece, então a ideia é otimizar todo o restante para tentar manter mais memória disponível para essas telas.

Comment: @Fernando nenhuma serviu ou esqueceu de aceitar uma delas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Algo muito importante sobre escopo é o tempo que seus objetos permanecerão na heap (Área da memória onde a JVM aloca os objetos).

Não sendo interessante que um objeto permaneça em memória além do necessário, então é importante SIM definir bem os escopos pois facilita o trabalho do Garbage Colector.

Então, respondendo suas perguntas:

> Isso faz realmente diferença de performance? Por que?

Talvez. É importantíssimo fazer bom uso dos recursos computacionais, principalmente quando falamos de celulares e gatgets do tipo.

Utilizar bem o conceito de escopo é apenas um fator positivo em seu código, mas não é tudo. Definir bem o escopo talvez não deixe seu programa mais rápido, mas o manterá robusto e consistente, diferente daqueles programas que vão ficando mais e mais lentos no fim do dia, obrigando-nos a dar reboots no mesmo.

> Se faz diferença, as abordagens 2 e 3 apresentam diferenças de
>   performance? Onde e por que?

Considerando o que eu disse na primeira resposta e analisando as abordagens, não. Olhando rapidamente as duas eu não vejo muita diferença entre elas.

Particularmente eu prefiro a abordagem dois, pois cada objeto vai existir durante a execução de seu respectivo método.

A abordagem 3 pode ser interessante em métodos muito grandes que alocam uma boa quantidade de objetos, mas mesmo assim eu consideraria um refactoring.

> Se isso faz algum sentido, seria uma boa prática ter isso em mente
>   para projetos robustos, principalmente pensando em dispositivos
>   moveis?

Sim. Se for comparar com um servidor, dispositivos móveis são muito limitados. Precisamos sempre ter em mente que um app que consome muitos recursos consome muita bateria, ninguém vai usar um app destes.

Answer (score 5):

**Não programe de um jeito amigável ao JIT, deixe ele fazer o trabalho**

Em uma HotSpot comum, digamos, uma versão muita usada na Indústria, como a JVM 6, diversos recursos existem para permitir que o código que você escreveu seja otimizado.

Você escreve um arquivo `.java`, ele é compilado para `.class` e então é executado dentro de uma JVM que compila em tempo de execução para código nativo.

Durante esse processo, acontecem fenomenos no seu código, entre eles:

- **Inline Expasion -** A chamada do método é substituida pelo corpo dele;
- **Reordering -** Seu código é reordenado para executar da maneira mais eficaz pelo processador;
- **Escape Analyses -** Cópias defensivas não são alocadas na memória se a JVM percebe que não são alteradas por código cliente (classes que fizeram chamada a métodos), Métodos sincronizados (*synchronized*) são chamados sem o *overhead* de tráfego no *Shared Memory Bus* da máquina, caso a JVM perceba que este método não é executado concorrentemente (recurso padrão a partir da versão 6u23 da HotSpot).

Esses fenômenos acontecem durante a execução do programa, que vai sendo otimizado baseado na sua utilização, é por isso que em muitos dispositivos Android, ao se reiniciar o sistema, ele está mais lento. O que não acontece mais a partir da versão 5.0 que utiliza ART, ou Android Runtime, que utiliza outra técnica, chamada de *A Head-of-time compilation*.

**Não utilize escopos/blocos de códio em nome da performance**

Otimização prematura vai te causar problemas de *design* e você terá códigos mais verbosos.

**A fato de um objeto sair de escopo do método não quer dizer que ele será coletado.**

O objeto sem referências fortes apenas será coletado no próximo ciclo do *Garbage Collector*, que geralmente ocorre em duas fases - *Major Collections* e *Minor Collections*, em suma ele pode permanecer no *heap* mesmo sem referência.

Recomendo fortemente que você veja este exemplo:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm#i1084566

Moral, dedique-se ao *design* primeiro, otimize depois.

Comment: +1. No caso particular do exemplo 1, muitos compiladores analisam a [vida das variáveis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis) (inglês), apesar de não saber se é o caso da JVM em particular, pra tirar esse tipo de conclusão.

Comment: Outra pegadinha é que como a função retorna uma `String` (e não e.g. um `int`), a JVM pode ter dificuldade de provar que essa string não aponta pra um membro compartilhado da `ClasseGrande`. Se tanto a string quanto a `ClasseGrande` vão ser destruídas ao final do método, OK. Caso contrário, o garbage collector vai ter que decidir quais membros da `ClasseGrande` ele vai ter que destruir, i.e. a versão com o escopo dá **mais** (e não **menos**) trabalho pro Java.

Answer (score 1):

A abordagem 2 e 3 não tem diferença, em ambos você dividiu o código em blocos separados para diminuir o escopo dos objetos.

Sobre a abordagem 1, se ainda tiver muito processamento a ser executado abaixo da linha:

```
String resultado = classeGrande.obtemResultado();
```

Você pode dividir ele em métodos diferentes tanto para facilitar a leitura, quando para poder liberar o objeto para o 'garbage collector' (não significa que ele será removido da memoria, apenas que ele está disponível).